# Django : how to create a mailbox for each users i have

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-users

I have a project with 3 groups of user who are **admin**, **prof**, and **student**. I want all my users to be able to send messages to each other privately. For example if I want a **teacher** to send a message to a **student** or **admin**, how should I proceed?
Do I need to create a new model or I just need to add a mailbox field to my models.

that's my models

### models.py

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField


class Prof(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)                                       
    location = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    phone = PhoneNumberField(blank=True)


class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    speciality = models.CharField(max_length=150)                                     
    location = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    phone = PhoneNumberField(blank=True)
```

here is how I register my 3 types of users with django signals

### signals.py

```py
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Prof, Student
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def admin_profil(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created and instance.is_superuser:
        group = Group.objects.get(name='admin')
        instance.groups.add(group)


@receiver(post_save, sender=Prof)
def prof_profil(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        group = Group.objects.get(name='prof')
        instance.user.groups.add(group)


@receiver(post_save, sender=Student)
def student_profil(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        group = Group.objects.get(name='student')
        instance.user.groups.add(group)
```

**precision:** i register my admin with the command line **createsuperuser** and the others user by forms

Answer (score 1):

> For example if I want a teacher to send a message to a student or admin, how should I proceed?

Since you already (prudently enough) have separated the role-specific fields from your users, your Message model can look like

```
class Message(models.Model):
   recipient = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='messages_received')
   sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='messages_sent')
   # ... other messagey fields
```

Then a view can request messages for the current user with e.g. `Message.objects.filter(recipient=request.user)` or similar.